# How do I list sub categories of the current ecommerce category in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-12

In Odoo (qweb template) I can't find how to list the sub categories of the ecommerce category that is active. There is a default "recursive" category list code but nowhere do I see any code to simply list the child.id categories of the current category that a user is on. I'm trying to make a sub category header list for people to drill down into what they want. I'm new to qweb fyi.

This is the recursive category list code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t name="Collapse Category Recursive" t-name="website_sale.option_collapse_categories_recursive">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <i t-if="categ.child_id" t-attf-class="text-primary fa #{'fa-chevron-down' if categ.id in parent_category_ids else 'fa-chevron-right'}" t-attf-title="#{'Unfold' if categ.id in parent_category_ids else 'Fold'}" t-attf-aria-label="#{'Unfold' if categ.id in parent_category_ids else 'Fold'}" role="img"/>
        <a t-att-href="keep('/shop/category/' + slug(categ), category=0)" t-attf-class="nav-link#{' active' if categ.id == int(category or 0) else ''}" t-field="categ.name"/>
        <ul t-if="categ.child_id" class="nav nav-pills flex-column nav-hierarchy" t-att-style="'display:block;' if categ.id in parent_category_ids else 'display:none;'">
            <t t-foreach="categ.child_id" t-as="categ">
                <t t-if="not search or categ.id in search_categories_ids">
                    <t t-call="website_sale.option_collapse_categories_recursive"/>
                </t>
            </t>
        </ul>
    </li>
</t>
```

I'm trying to basically do the opposite and show only what is a child cat of the current "categ.id".

eg: If "categ.id" has "categ.child_id"s then foreach through them in a list.

Any pointers or links to existing code would be really really helpful.

Thank you!

As a side-note, isn't listing subcats like a standard ecommerce thing? I'm surprised this is not present as normal in odoo.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In Odoo Studio create a related one to many field that is category children.

Then this:

```
<t t-if="category">
   <t t-foreach="category.x_studio_children" t-as="v">
          <t t-if="category.x_studio_children">
            <span t-field="v.name"/> 
          </t>
        </t>
</t>
```